# Anti-concentration bounds for folded normal and inverse of gaussian variables

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, inequalities, measure-concentration

Are there any easy to use bounds on sums of the following kind :

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{i = N} |a_i| \geq P  \\
a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1) \\
$$

and also for sums of the form :

$$
\sum_{i = 1}^{i = M} \frac{1}{|\frac{k}{b_i} - \frac{1}{a_i}|} \leq Q\\
b_i, k \in \mathbb{R}, a_i \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)
$$

For the first one, one way to approach it would be to use the folded normal distribution's cdf, this provides a bound on each of the elements taking a large value. This bound as it stands is very weak, and not completely useful (although would be appreciated as well). Another approach would be to bound this as $\sum |a_i| \geq N * \min{|a_i|}$.

For the second one, an approach I had was to analyze the sum $|b_i - a_i|$ via an anti-concentration bound for gaussians, but again I have not found much literature on this.

Comment: The first sum will have mean $n\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ and if the $|a_i|$ are independent then variance $n\left(1-{\frac{2}{\pi}}\right)$ with usual central limit theorem properties.  If the $|a_i|$ are perfectly correlated, then you have a scaled half-normal distribution

Comment: Of course, you are right. I need a stronger result than that, unfortunately. Is it possible to make an anti-concentration claim stronger than what we would get using Markov/Chernoff?